# Exponential Twisting

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation, monte-carlo, exponential-family, importance-sampling

I am with a difficult to prove the next relation about exponential twisting.

According to Monte Carlo Methods and Models in Finance and Insurance by Ralf Korn, Elke Korn, Gerald Kroisandt.

The method of exponential twisting is given by:
[image]

I am trying to prove that in fact 
$$C'(\theta)=E[X \exp(\theta'X-C(\theta))]=E_{\theta}(X)$$

I have the next steps:

First I know by the definition given that $M(\theta)=E(\exp(\theta'X))$, then the function $C(\theta)=ln(E(\exp(\theta'X)))$.

I need to compute the derivative, in that case, I am looking for $$\frac{dC(\theta)}{d\theta}=\frac{dE[\exp(\theta'X)]}{E[\exp(\theta'X)]}$$ 
using the derivative of the natural logarithm.

Now, I note that $E(X)=\int x f(x)dx$ then, If I take the derivative on both sides I get: $$\frac{dEX}{dx}=xf(x)dx$$.

It the derivative of the expectation is equal to the argument $x$ times the density function, times the differential of the variable , i.e.
$$C'(\theta)=\frac{\exp(\theta'X)}{E(\exp(\theta' X))}xf(x)$$

Then I note that $\frac{\exp(\theta'X)}{E(\exp(\theta' X))}f(x)=f_\theta(x)$

From here I am a little bit confused with my proof, maybe something of my justifications are not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble with the derivative of a moment generating function. The reason they have the name they have is because they generate (via differentiation) moments (as long as you set $\theta$ equal to zero after). For moment generating functions, you can interchange the order of integration and differentiation. This means $\frac{d}{d\theta}E[e^{\theta'x}] = E\left[\frac{d}{d\theta}e^{\theta'x}\right] = E\left[X e^{\theta'X}\right]$.

Here are the rest of the steps.

\begin{align*}
C'(\theta) &= \frac{d}{d\theta} C(\theta) \tag{defn}  \\ 
&= \frac{d}{d\theta} \ln M(\theta) \tag{defn} \\ 
&= \frac{M'(\theta)}{M(\theta)}\tag{chain rule}  \\ 
&= \frac{ E[X \exp(\theta'X)] }{\exp(\log M(\theta))}\tag{prop. of mgf}  \\ 
&=E[X \exp(\theta'X)]  \exp( - \log M(\theta))  \tag{algebra} \\ 
&=E[X \exp(\theta'X- \log M(\theta))] \tag{algebra} \\ 
&=E[X \exp(\theta'X- C(\theta))] \tag{defn}
\end{align*}